# How to allow user to paste image on web page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to allow user to paste image on web page. After researching on Stack Overflow O did find a way to paste image using canvas but every time I select an element in drop down the canvas also gets reset. Is there any other way I can do that? I also need to get the path of image which I'm unable to get through canvas.

```html
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    1. Copy image data into clipboard or press Print Screen <br>
2. Press Ctrl+V (page/iframe must be focused):
<br /><br />
<canvas contenteditable style="border:1px solid grey;" id="cc" width="200" height="200">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("cc");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //=== Clipboard ===============================

    window.addEventListener("paste", pasteHandler); //chrome
    //handler
    function pasteHandler(e) {
        if (e.clipboardData == false) return false; //empty
        var items = e.clipboardData.items;
        if (items == undefined) return false;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") == -1) continue; //not image
            var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
            var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var source = URLObj.createObjectURL(blob);
            paste_createImage(source);
        }
    }
    //draw pasted object
    function paste_createImage(source) {
        var pastedImage = new Image();
        pastedImage.onload = function () {
            ctx.drawImage(pastedImage, 0, 0);
        }
        pastedImage.src = source;
    }

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Maybe you should post your code <3

Comment: Dropzone.js will help you. see example here http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0R5L90S then go to Forms > File Upload.

Comment: How can i add my code here can anybody giud me/

Comment: okay guys i sorted a way i put all drop downs in update panel so it wont reset the canvas. Now i want to save the image pasted in canvas to a folder is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Dropdown into the Update panel. So that it will not refresh the whole page, hence your pasted image will not disappear.

Or else

Please Refer on this link.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/copying-and-pasting-on-clipboard-using-C-Sharp/

First store image in clip board, then after dropdown selection changed call the clipboard image and load it into the image box.

Comment: thankyou but can u answer the next problem i have mentioned in comment i.e. want to save the image pasted in canvas to a folder is it possible and how?

Comment: Also i want to save that image in database and then retrieve it. Will it be possible through canvas. I have tried so many ways :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have UpdatePanel, every time an auto postback is triggered, everything is reset. The solution is quite simple. Store your data in a hidden field:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">                      
                function AlPegar(event) {
                    var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
                    var blob = null;
                    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                        if (items[i].type.indexOf("image") === 0) {
                            blob = items[i].getAsFile();
                        }
                    }
                    if (blob !== null) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (event) {
                            document.getElementById("<%= ImgPegar.ClientID %>").src = event.target.result;
                            document.getElementById("<%= HdnImagen.ClientID %>").value = event.target.result;
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("<%= ImgPegar.ClientID %>").src = "";
                        document.getElementById("<%= HdnImagen.ClientID %>").value = "";
                    }
                };
            </script>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPegar" runat="server" 
                TextMode="MultiLine" 
                Rows="2" 
                Columns="20" 
                onpaste="AlPegar(event)" 
                placeholder="Pegue aquí la imagen"
                OnTextChanged="TxtPegar_TextChanged" />
            <img id="ImgPegar" name="ImgPegar" src="" width="150" runat="server" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="HdnImagen" runat="server" />
```

Restore image on Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            // Restore image after PostBack
            ImgPegar.Src = HdnImagen.Value;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Bitacora.Guardar(ex);
        Response.Redirect(UtilsInet.UrlError, false);
    }
}
```